# Are there other seeds that repel liquid like Safflower seeds?

Tags: seeds

I am transitioning to using natural products for my cat litter and have seen many people recommending the use of Safflower seed for their liquid-repelling properties.

However, Safflower seeds are quite hard to obtain in Australia in bulk.  Are there any other commonly available seeds that have a similar liquid-repelling nature?

Comment: Are you talking about the oil pressed from the seeds? Are you actually pressing your own oil?

Comment: Hi Bulrush. No I'm wanting to use seeds for my cat's litter. Perhaps you missd that in the first line.  An example of safflower seed use in a litter tray can be seen here: http://www.thecatsask.com/

Comment: Coconut husks *may* work. The things float between islands before sprouting. Can't get the stuff here to test, but It's got to be cheap in tropical areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are other commonly available seeds that have a similar liquid-repelling nature: some of the easiest to get are [flaxseeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax). Generally speaking, any seed that has a glossy, lustruous appearance, is water-repelling on the short-term.

(On a sidenote, don't forget that your house will smell like vinegar 24/7 because of the safflower seed litterbox.)

Comment: Thanks. Flaxseeds could be great, especially being so small. Yeah the odour may be an issue! But this is worth trialling all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want substances that take the place of cat litter in function, that function being to absorb, not repel liquid.  Whatever you were using to get the false information should be discarded.  If the seed were liquid repellent then you  might as well just use pebbles or marbles then wash them and reuse.  Or sand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was asking because I was looking to either buy this innovative litter tray: https://www.thecatsask.com/how-it-works or build one like it for myself. As you'll see, absorption is not the feature of this setup.